# Mongodb aggregation lookup out put and again perform lookup on the output

Tags: mongodb, collections, match, lookup, aggregation

the query is as shown below

```
db.assignmentdetails.aggregate([
{ "$match": { _id: ObjectId("614887ee0e02d153ecc6dbc3") } },
  { "$addFields": {
        "convertedClassId": { $toObjectId: "$className" },
   
      }
    }},
       {
      "$lookup": {
        "from": "combinedgradesectiondetails",
        "localField": "convertedClassId",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "classDetails"
      }
    },
      
])
```

output:

```
{
            "_id" : ObjectId("614872917500193be80ca896"),
            "gradeId" : "6148728f7500193be80ca86d",
            "sectionId" : "614872917500193be80ca892",
            "maximumStudents" : 35,
            "maximumCourse" : 5,
            "updated" : ISODate("2021-09-20T11:37:53.499Z"),
            "__v" : 0
        }
```

here again on this output i have to perform lookup on gradeId from another collection (grade details) sectionId from another collection (section details) but this as to be done only on this output of the existing quire not sure is there a way in mongoDB aggregation please point to a documentation or a sample  quire to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can chain $lookup one after another.

Use $unwind to flatten the array if needed.

Optionally you can use $project stage after every $lookup so that further stages are supplied with only required fields.

Here is a reference example:

```
[{
    $match: {
        status: "ACTIVE"
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'place',
        localField: 'place_id',
        foreignField: 'place_id',
        as: 'place'
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: '$place'
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        custom_hour_id: 1,
        place_id: 1,
        menu_id: 1,
        object_type: 1,
        description: 1,
        day: 1,
        option: 1,
        closed_all_day: 1,
        status: 1,
        audit: 1,
        place: {
            place_id: 1,
            name: 1,
            city: 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'user_DEV1',
        localField: 'audit.created_by',
        foreignField: 'user_id',
        as: 'created_by_user'
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: '$created_by_user'
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        custom_hour_id: 1,
        place_id: 1,
        menu_id: 1,
        object_type: 1,
        description: 1,
        day: 1,
        option: 1,
        closed_all_day: 1,
        status: 1,
        audit: 1,
        place: 1,
        created_by_user: {
            user_id: 1,
            email: 1,
            display_name: 1
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: true but the output of first lookup i want to use in the second

Comment: First stage output is second stage input and this continues until last stage.